# Can we load core css files from custom theme with yml lib?

Tags: 8

Is there a way to provide f.e normalize.css within my custom template using a *.libraries.yml config file? Tried the following, didnt work out.
I was just wondering if this would be possbile, for it seems to be nice, while the file comes with drupal8 installation.

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
    core:
      normalize-css/normalize.css: {}
  js:
    dependencies:
      - core/modernizr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first attempt to load the single file `normalize.css` is not correct. If you want to do it this way, you have to use the full path to this file.

But this is not the preferred way to do this. You don't know if in future the position of this file will change. Better use the library already defined in core, as you have done in the second attempt to load modernizr. This will work, if you put the key `dependencies` on the first level of the array, for example see the core library `date`:

```
drupal.date:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    misc/date.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/modernizr
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
```

If you look for normalize.css, this is defined in core:

```
normalize:
  remote: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css
  version: "3.0.3"
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/LICENSE.md
    gpl-compatible: true
  css:
    base:
      assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css: { weight: -20 }
```

And you can use it as dependency in *.libraries.yml:

```
  dependencies:
    - core/normalize
```

Or as library in the theme.info.yml file:

```
libraries:
  - core/normalize
```

If you use a core library, you don't have to put it in your own library, you can choose the direct way to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.Especially for the core.libraries file which is in drupal core folder!